# DataReader already opened and must be closed. I don't understand

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, session

I am modelling a database to insert movies and movies' sessions in theaters. I understand that a theater has many sessions and a session has a movie and a theater.

```
public class Movie
    {
        public int MovieID { get; set; }
        public String MovieName { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        public int Rate { get; set; }
    }

public class Theater
    {
        public int TheaterID { get; set; }
        public String TheaterName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    }

public class Session
    {
        public int SessionID { get; set; }
        public int MovieID { get; set; }
        public int TheaterID { get; set; }
        public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
        public virtual Theater Theater { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a view which receives a set of sessions. In this view I use a foreach to show the theater name and all movies in that:

This is the code from the controller:

```
 public ActionResult MoviesSessions(int id)
        {
            Theater theater = db.Theater.Find(id);
            ViewBag.TheaterName = Theater.TheaterName;
            var sessions = from s in db.Sessions where s.TheaterID == id orderby s.MovieID select s;
            return View(sessions);
        }
```

And this is inside the view:

```
@{
        string theaterName = "";
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            if (theaterName != item.Theater.TheaterName)
            {
                theaterName = item.Theater.TheaterName;
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Movie.MovieName)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    }
```

Because I'm using `item.Movie.MovieName` I'm receiving the following error:

> "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

Is the Movie object wasn't already populated in the controller query? I don't understand why I'm getting this error. It's my first time working with asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to simply set `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` in connection string. Since you are looping through a query, you are reading first object and then you are trying to load `item.Theater.TheaterName` , since it has a navigation property and it is not included in the query, EF will fire a second query to load `item.Theater.TheaterName`, since previous query is yet not finished as your enumeration is not finished. It will throw an error if MultipleActiveResultSet is not set to true. Setting it true will allow EF to open multiple open queries on same connection.

```
  connectionString="Data Source=MATT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;" + 
             "Initial Catalog=Raise;Integrated Security=True;" + 
             "MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
```

OR

Other way around is, to either use `ToList` or `include`

```
 // .ToList() will force entire query to load and close data reader
 foreach(var m in Model.ToList()){
      ....
 }
```

OR

```
 // since you are only interested in Theater, you could eager load 
 // Theater, this will cause EF to load Theater along with Movies in single
 // query
 foreach(var m in Model.Include("Theater")){
      ....
 }
```

RECOMMENDED

```
 foreach(var m in Model.Include("Theater").ToList()){
      ....
 }
```

Many would argue that this causes dual enumeration in code, but this also reduces open query time on sql server which helps in reducing transaction deadlocks and timeouts. Under the hood, SQL query is open for entire enumeration, and inside a transaction, it definitely hurts SQL's performance.

Comment: I didn't know about MultipleActiveResultSets. Inserting ToList is better than Include?

Comment: I would always use `ToList()`, this reduces database deadlocks as query is not open for entire enumeration  , you can also use `Include("Theater").ToList()`, this is preferred as everything will be loaded in single query. If your database is on different or remote machine (Sql Azure), using `Include("Theater")` will require single trip to bring data and `Include("Theater").ToList()` is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The item.Movie property is a deferred query and is trying to execute another database query using the same connection that is return the results from the first query. Some database connections only allow one active stream of results at a time, so you would have to first read all the rows/entities before you can start exploring.  You can easily do this by calling .ToList on the query (sessions) before passing it to the View function.  Also, if you are using SQL server, you can set "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" in the connection string.

Comment: I didn't know about MultipleActiveResultSets. Executing another query hurts performance? Is there another to do that in just one query?

Comment: If you are using EF, then Include might do it in one query, or just buffer results for you (equivalent of you using .ToList).  I'm not sure what the implementation does.  L2S equivalent to Include would have done one query with an outer join.